# How to stop adding duplicate records after every refresh of the page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I created a registration form, where I accept the name, gender, address, dob, and state. after submitting it, it gives the message **that the record is added** and shows an empty form, but if I refresh the page, it adds a duplicate record. a number of time I refresh the page the number of time same record is added this happen on after user registration confirmation. I want to add record only when i click on submit button. Please give me the solution using django

I want to add record only when I click on submit button or add record button of form, but It creating a record after first record added and success message display if i refresh here multiple times then multiple same records will be added to the database

Code:

views.py

```
def std_registration_view(request,username):
    if 'UserIsActive' in request.session:
        form=Student_Registration
        if request.method=="POST":
            form=Student_Registration(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                name=form.cleaned_data['full_name']
                messages.success(request,"Record is added for "+name)
                form=Student_Registration
                return render(request,'std_registration/registration.html',{"username":username,'form':form,'msg':'Record added'})
        return render(request,'std_registration/registration.html',{"username":username,'form':form})
    return redirect('login')
```

registrations.html

```
{% extends "login/base.html"%}
{% block title%}
<title>
    Registration
</title>
{%endblock%}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <h3 style="background-color: rgb(245, 250, 255,0.5);text-decoration: wavy;text-align: center;">Welcome {{username}}</h3>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card" style="opacity: 0.9;">
        <div class="card-header">Student Registration:{%for msg in messages%} <large style="color:rgb(242, 13, 13); text-decoration: solid;">{{msg}}</small> {%endfor%}</div>
        <div class="card-body" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="{{ form.full_name.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Full Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.full_name }}
                <span class="label label-warning" style="color: red;">{{form.full_name.errors}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Gender</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  {{ form.gender }}
                  <span class="label label-warning" style="color: red;">{{form.gender.errors}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="{{ form.dob.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Date of Birth</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.dob }}
                <span class="label label-warning" style="color: red;">{{form.dob.errors}}</span>
              </div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="{{ form.address.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Address</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.address }}
                <span class="label label-warning" style="color: red;">{{form.address.errors}}</span>
              </div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="{{ form.state.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">State</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.state }}
                <span class="label label-warning" style="color: red;">{{form.state.errors}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="{{ form.image.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <br>
                {{ form.image }}
                <span class="label label-warning" style="color: red;">{{form.image.errors}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn row ">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4"><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <a href="/display/" class="btn btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-trash">View Record</i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator,RegexValidator
from .models import Student
import datetime

choose_gender=[('Male','Male'),('Female','Female'),('Other','Other')]
union_territories = [
                            ("Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands"),
                            ("Chandigarh", "Chandigarh"),
                            ("Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu", "Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu"),
                            ("Lakshadweep", "Lakshadweep"),
                            ('Delhi','Delhi')]
STATE_CHOICES = sorted([
        ('Andhra Pradesh', 'Andhra Pradesh'),
        ('Arunachal Pradesh', 'Arunachal Pradesh'),
        ('Assam', 'Assam'),
        ('Bihar', 'Bihar'),
        ('Chhattisgarh', 'Chhattisgarh'),
        ('Goa', 'Goa'),
        ('Gujarat', 'Gujarat'),
        ('Haryana', 'Haryana'),
        ('Himachal Pradesh', 'Himachal Pradesh'),
        ('Jharkhand', 'Jharkhand'),
        ('Karnataka', 'Karnataka'),
        ('Kerala', 'Kerala'),
        ('Madhya Pradesh', 'Madhya Pradesh'),
        ('Maharashtra', 'Maharashtra'),
        ('Manipur', 'Manipur'),
        ('Meghalaya', 'Meghalaya'),
        ('Mizoram', 'Mizoram'),
        ('Nagaland', 'Nagaland'),
        ('Odisha', 'Odisha'),
        ('Punjab', 'Punjab'),
        ('Rajasthan', 'Rajasthan'),
        ('Sikkim', 'Sikkim'),
        ('Tamil Nadu', 'Tamil Nadu'),
        ('Telangana', 'Telangana'),
        ('Tripura', 'Tripura'),
        ('Uttarakhand', 'Uttarakhand'),
        ('Uttar Pradesh', 'Uttar Pradesh'),
        ('West Bengal', 'West Bengal'),
    ]+union_territories,key=lambda x:x[0])
    
class Student_Registration(forms.ModelForm):
    full_name=forms.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[a-zA-Z]{2,30}$',message='only alphabets allowed.')],widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),max_length=100,required=True)
    gender=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=choose_gender,required=True)
    dob=forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,required=True,widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'date'}),label='Date of Birth')
    address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),required=True)
    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),required=True)
    image=forms.ImageField(validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg','jpeg','png'],message='Only .jpg,.jpeg,.png files are allowed.'),])
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super().clean()
        image=self.cleaned_data['image']
        image_size=image.size
        if image_size>1000*1024 or image_size<10*1024:
            self.add_error('image','The image size must be more than 10kb and less than 1mb')
        return cleaned_data
    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields="__all__"
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('registration/<str:username>',views.std_registration_view,name='stdregistration'),
    path('display/',views.display_view,name='display'),
    path('update/<int:pk>',views.update_view,name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>',views.delete_view,name='delete')
]
```

Comment: Maybe you can add unique constraints in model, for example, make full name + address unique. Then if you submit the form multiple times by mistake, it will throw errors

Comment: no i found the better option instead of render to same page redirect to same page... that solve the issue of duplicate record creation...